# Synchronized shared definition in Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

Is there a way in Pentaho to create a synchronized shared definition?

Let say we have a source file s1 which is used in two transformations t1, t2. Now, suppose if I make change in t1 and add one more column in s1 there, I want it to get reflected in t2 too. Is there a way in Pentaho to achieve this?

When we share database connection in Pentaho all the changes gets reflected where ever we are using it. Can we do the similar thing with files too(if I am creating a shared definition of file and storing it in repository and then using it in other transformations)?

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I would recommend using a subtransformation for shared logic.  But in this case, the number of fields in the resulting stream is going to change, so the subtransformation won't buy you much; you would still need to go into the parent transformations to change the stream metadata.

Another approach is to use the Metadata Injection step, so that you can have dynamic stream structures.  This is probably overkill if you only have one source file used in two transformations, but if you have lots of source files shared by lots of transformations, it is a good approach.  There are multiple sources on the web on how to use this step; one such can be found [here](http://blog.oncase.com.br/using-pdi-metadata-injection-to-import-csv-files/).

Comment: Thanks @Ken for the response.

The way I found to achieve this is:
Let say I have a source file File.xlsx at C:\Users\Desktop. Now I can create a variable in kettle properties called INPUT_FILE. The value of this variable will be C:\Users\Desktop\File.xlsx i.e. the file location. Now, when in T1, for file location, I would just call ${INPUT_FILE}. Same thing for T2. If the location of this file changes, I will just edit the INPUT_FILE and change the location and if I need to change anything in the file the change will reflect in all the transformation as they are referring to a common file.

Comment: Kettle properties seems to be an awfully global way to refer to a single file.  Presumably you might need to process other input files at some time?